# SQL query with ORDER BY inside two different groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a simple table with NBA players:

id,player,mp,ppg (mp - matches played, ppg - points per game).

I need a query that gets all the guys but split the result into two parts:

- players who played in more or equal  30 games ordered by PPG desc,
- players who played less than 30 games ordered by PPG desc

So desirable output would be (example):

```
n. player    mp ppg

1. player1   82 32.5
2. player2   56 32.1
3. player3   82 29.7
4. player4   80 27.6
```

...

```
70. player70 75 1.5  (lowest in the 30+ games group)
71. player71 29 35.7 (highest in the less than 30 games group)
72. player72 19 31.3
```

...

Group 1) comes first (is more important) so even if PPG in group 2) is higher than the best one in group 1) it goes down after the worst PPG in the group where players have more than 30 games played.

Is there a way to do that in just one query? I'm using mySQL. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a typo in the your description, you said that the two would be `ordered by PPG desc` in the two cases ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, player, mp, ppg
from 
    playerTable
order by if (mp>=30, 1, 0) desc, ppg desc, mp desc`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN mp >= 30 THEN PPG END DESC,
    CASE WHEN mp < 30 THEN PPG END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ppq` is allways lower than 1000000, this would work:

```
SELECT 
  * -- or whatever you want
FROM players
ORDER BY IF(mp>=30,1000000+ppg,mp) desc
```

This assumes, that the second group is ordered by `mp` desc (as in example), not by `ppg` (as in text)

Answer (score 0):

First order by MP>30 then by PPG

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN mp >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ASC, PPG DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select player, mp, ppg
from t
order by mp < 30, ppg desc
```